# How to select coefficient of an exponential function

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

Suppose I have these set of equations:

```
sol = DSolve[{
x'[t] == -RandomReal[]*x[t] + y[t],
y'[t] == x[t] - *y[t] ,
x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

The solution is always in this form:

```
x[t] = a*Exp[k1*t] + b*Exp[k2*t]

y[t] = c*Exp[k1*t] + d*Exp[k2*t]
```

I want the coefficient of `Exp[k1*t]` in both solution, like:

```
{a, c}
```

I want the same list for `Exp[k2*t]`:

```
{b, d}
```

The solution must be generizable to a system of three or more equations.

Comment: What makes $e^{-0.0305607 t}$ special? As you stated, the solution will change so how can you be certain that this term will be in all solutions. Perhaps you are looking for the coefficient of the most negative exponent in t, or something like that?

Comment: That is just an example. I want to solve the equation and automatically get the coefficient of the exponential with the same exponent in x[t] or y[t].

Comment: Please update the question by editing it and state in the question that you want to select coefficients for matching exponents in the functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
Cases[a, coeff_.*e^(-0.0305607 t) :> coeff, 2]
```

> {0.678839}

```
Cases[b, coeff_.*e^(-0.0305607 t) :> coeff, 2]
```

> {-0.660328}

The pattern `coeff_.` would work even if the coefficient were 1, e.g.

```
Cases[{e^(-0.0305607 t)}, coeff_.*e^(-0.0305607 t) :> coeff, 2]
```

> {1}

because the dot, signifying default value, defaults to 1 in the case of a product like here. OTOH, the pattern without the dot does not work:

```
Cases[{e^(-0.0305607 t)}, coeff_*e^(-0.0305607 t) :> coeff, 2]
```

> {}

Comment: The solution to the equation will change when I add more terms or change the equation. Is it possible to select the coefficient without explicit use of the solution?

Comment: In order to even have coefficients you have to solve the equation, don't you?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. In addition, The expressions `a` and `b` are undefined and seem unrelated to the `a` and `b` in the OP.  I suspect `e` should be `E`. @MOON, this is really your fault for changing the question so much as to make the answers seem irrelevant.

Comment: The first argument of Cases[ ] should be a List. So the formula such as $a*Exp[b]$ which is a List can be used, but  $Exp[b]$ is not a List which should be enclosed with {}. How to use the same function both on $a*Exp[b]$ and $Exp[b]$? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Coefficient[a, E^(-0.03056065153782187` t)]
Coefficient[b, E^(-0.03056065153782187` t)]

(*  {0.678839}

{-0.660328}  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
lst[inp_] := Module[{apt, expr},
  expr = inp;
  apt[x_] := {x[[1]], x[[2, 2, 1]]};
  SetAttributes[apt, Listable];
  expr[[0]] = List;
  SortBy[apt[expr], Last]
  ]
```

`lst[a*Exp[k1*t] + b*Exp[k2*t] + c*Exp[k3*t]]` returns a list sorted by k1,k2,...:

`{{a, k1}, {b, k2}, {c, k3}}`.

This may only work when `a,b,c,k1,k2,k3` are numbers due to different positioning for symbol names, where the indices of `apt[]` may not work. You can run `lst` on the solutions and use the following to find the common factors:

```
srh[ls1_, ls2_] := Module[{r},
  r = {};
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[ls1], i++,
   If[ls1[[i, 2]] == ls2[[i, 2]],
    AppendTo[r, {{ls1[[i, 1]], ls2[[i, 1]]}, ls2[[i, 2]]}]]
     ];
  Return[r]]
```

example:

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f} = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 6]
(*{-8.6537, 2.71094, 6.72124, -7.33271, -6.48603, -2.0651}*)
{k1, k2, k3} = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]
(*{-0.164005, 0.649829, 0.978501}*)
r1 = lst[a*Exp[k1*t] + b*Exp[k2*t] + c*Exp[k3*t]];
r2 = lst[d*Exp[k1*t] + e*Exp[k2*t] + f*Exp[k3*t]];
srh[r1, r2]
(*{{{-8.6537, -7.33271}, -0.164005},
  {{2.71094, -6.48603}, 0.649829},
  {{6.72124, -2.0651}, 0.978501}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

LaplaceTransform[x[t],t,s] will give you a function with poles in s at k1 and k2. The residues of these poles are the coefficients that you want.  So
Residue[LaplaceTransform[x[t],t,s],{s,k1}]= a.

In your case, you know the locations of the poles in advance.  If you did not, you could determine them using TransferFunctionPoles[
 TransferFunctionModel[{{LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s]}}, s]], and work things out from there.

Answer (score 0):

Look at you results with TreeForm and pick the coefficient through indexing.

```
TreeForm[a*Exp[k1*t] + b*Exp[k2*t]]
```

[image]

So you can see that `a` can be extracted as `%[[1, 1]]`

Answer (score 0):

A bit of linear algebra never hurt anyone.  First, we tweak the code a bit.  The following code is equivalent to your original, except it stores the matrix implicit in the linear system in memory and allows for arbitrary initial conditions in `ics`:

```
mat = {{-RandomReal[], 1}, {1, -1}}
ics = {1, 0};
sol = Expand[DSolve[{{x'[t], y'[t]} == mat.{x[t], y[t]}, x[0] == 1,  y[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]]

(* {{-0.184931, 1}, {1, -1}} *)
(* {{x[t] -> 0.311301 E^(-1.67232 t) + 0.688699 E^(0.487388 t), y[t] -> -0.463026 E^(-1.67232 t) + 0.463026 E^(0.487388 t)}} *)
```

Once you've done this, then a bit of linear algebra is all you need to figure out the coefficients:

```
Eigenvalues[mat]
(Eigenvectors[mat].ics)*Eigenvectors[mat]

(* {-1.67232, 0.487388} *)
(* {{0.311301, -0.463026}, {0.688699, 0.463026}} *)
```

In the two lists, the items in the first list are $k_1$ & $k_2$;  the corresponding items in the second list are the coefficients of $e^{k_i t}$ in the solutions for $x(t)$ & $y(t)$, respectively.

This method scales in a natural way to an arbitrary number of functions $x(t), y(t), ...$;  simply modify the size of the initial matrix `mat` to be $n \times n$, and adjust the length of `ics` to be $n$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
GroupBy[Cases[Expand[sol], a_*E^b_ :> {a, b}, Infinity], 
 Last -> First]

(*<|-1.66951564692 t -> {0.309512052202, -0.462292485061}, 
 0.493617071683 t -> {0.690487947798, 0.462292485061}|>*)

%//Values
(*{{0.309512052202, -0.462292485061}, {0.690487947798, 0.462292485061}}*)

GroupBy[Cases[{x[t] == a*Exp[k1*t] + b*Exp[k2*t], 
   y[t] == c*Exp[k1*t] + d*Exp[k2*t]}, a_*E^b_ :> {a, b}, Infinity], 
 Last -> First]

(*<|k1 t -> {a, c}, k2 t -> {b, d}|>*)
```